# Why do I need `text: model.display.foo` instead of just `text: foo` when using a C++ QAbstractListModel?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm *very* new with Qt / QtQuick.

I have [a simple form](https://github.com/tobiatesan/qt_example/blob/master/MainForm.ui.qml) designed with Qt Designer which consists uniquely of a `ListView`.

```
Item {
    // ... 
    ListView {
        id: listView1
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: FooModel
        delegate: Item {
            // ... 
            Row {
                id: row1
                Text {
                    text: foo
                    // ... 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine with the following - either by copy-pasting it inline as `model`, or by letting `qmlscene` or Qt Designer notice the [`FooModel.qml`](https://github.com/tobiatesan/qt_example/blob/master/dummydata/FooModel.qml) contained in `dummydata`:

```
ListModel {
    ListElement {
        foo: "1"
    }

    ListElement {
        foo: "2"
    }

    ListElement {
        foo: "3"
    }

    ListElement {
        foo: "4"
    }
}
```

*However*, when I try to replace my dummy model with [an actual C++ model](https://github.com/tobiatesan/qt_example/blob/master/foolistmodel.cpp) that subclasses `QAbstractListModel`, I have to replace `text: foo` with `text: model.display.foo` in the `delegate`:

```
delegate: Item {
        // ... 
        Row {
            id: row1
            Text {
                text: model.display.foo // <=== See? 
                // ... 
            }
        }
    }
```

If I don't, Qt complains that

> qrc:/MainForm.ui.qml:23: ReferenceError: foo is not defined

and nothing is displayed.

I set the model property like this, [in my `main.cpp`](https://github.com/tobiatesan/qt_example/blob/master/main.cpp):

```
FooListModel* flm= new FooListModel();
QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("FooModel", flm);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
return app.exec();
```

**Why is this?**

Also - assuming "it's a feature and not a bug" - having to change the `text` attribute means that I can no longer have my dummy data in QtDesigner or use inline models for prototyping; **can I avoid this in any way?**

---

*Please find the MWE in question [here on Github](https://github.com/tobiatesan/qt_example).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qrc:/MainForm.ui.qml:23: ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Means you have to define `foo` role in the `FooListModel`. For example,

```
class FooListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    enum FooListModelRoles 
    {
        FooRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        BarRole, 
        //...
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const //override
    {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roleName;
        roleName[FooRole] = "foo";  //define "foo" role for QML
        roleName[BarRole] = "bar";  //define "bar" role for QML
        return roleName;
    }

    //...
}
```

And delegates in QML can access `foo` role now.

> Also - assuming "it's a feature and not a bug"

Yes, `text: model.display.foo` works fine because `display` is a pre-defined role in [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames).

Comment: Oh, so `text: blah` doesn't mean *the property `blah`*? Thank you very much, I was taking that pretty much for granted.

Comment: In `FooListModel::data()` function, the second argument says role is an int, however in QML `foo` is a string. That means you need a method to convert string to int for each role. And that method is `roleNames()` .

Comment: Wonderful. You saved me a migraine. Thank you.